# Calculate array element frequency without repetition

Tags: java, arrays

I want to find the frequency of the array elements. Like:

Input array:

```
1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,8
```

Expected output (digit frequency):

```
1 1
2 2
3 2
4 2
5 1
8 1
```

My Java code is:

```
class Fre 
{ 
 public static void main(String ar[]) 
 {
  frequencycount(new int[]{1,2,3,3,2,1,1,1,5,6,5,8,9,6}); 
 }


 static void frequencycount(int x[])
 {
  int i=0; 
  int j=0; 
  int fr[]=new int[x.length];
   for(i=0;i<fr.length;i++) { 
     fr[i]=0;
    }

    /////calculating frequency
    for(i=0;i<digit.length;i++) { 
       for(j=0;j<digit.length;j++) { 
          if(x[i]==x[j]) {
            fr[i]++; 
          }
        }
      } 

  for(i=0;i<fr.length;i++) { 
      System.out.println(x[i]+" "+fr[i]);
    } 
  }
 }//class
```

The problem with the output is it is repeating the array elements. Like:

```
digit frequency:


1 1
2 2
3 2
4 2
2 2
3 2
4 2
7 1
8 1
```

How can I get the desired frequencies without repeating the array elements? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Think over, What are your unique values, what happens when you iterate to reach a value that is already counted once.. Also not sure how are you printing those two values every row.

Comment: I think instead of `x[i]` you should print `i`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 why?

Comment: because you want to show the frequency of the digits that you are storing as index of `fr` array , e.g for `fr[3] = 2` , you want to print `3 2` only you have check whether fr[i] is zero or not

Comment: Whats `digit.length`? The output you gave is not the output of your code, did you even try to solve it on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use map like `Map<Integer, Integer>` and increase the the value of the key each time you find the value? Then you can loop through the map and print out it's values. This also saves you from the nested for loop.

[Here's a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm) to get you started on using `Map`

Comment: You might want to replace `Map<int,int>` with `Map<Integer,Integer>`

Comment: @ArchdukeLiamus forgot generics can't use primitives, thanks

Comment: @user227666 I'll try to fix up something using just arrays

Comment: @EthanBar that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of compilation and logical error in your code.Instead, I use below code.

```
class Fre {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        frequencycount(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 5, 8, 9, 6});
    }


    static void frequencycount(int x[]) {

        int fr[] = new int[maxElement(x)];
        /* default value of all elements is 0 no need to run this code
        for (i = 0; i < fr.length; i++) {
            fr[i] = 0;
        }*/


        for (int k = 0; k < x.length; k++) {
            //update index with count
            int value = x[k];
            fr[value] = fr[value] + 1;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < fr.length; k++) {
            if (fr[k] != 0) {
                System.out.println(k+" " + fr[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting arrayindexOutofBound error in line `fr[value] = fr[value] + 1;`

Comment: The problem here is int fr[] = new int[x.length]; you have to define the length as the maximum element instead of x.length.

Comment: @user227666 Without using maps, you'll need an array that is as long as the range of values you might need to accept. Either you'll have to make your own `Map` like function, or just make a stupid long array,

Comment: Agree @EthanBar Generic is the better way. In case of array, there will be lots of 0 elements

Comment: The range is only 10 values(the digits), make the length of `fr[] 10` and it will work.